# Why sometimes the selected answer is not the top answer?

Tags: support, accepted-answer, votes, sorting

I was under the impression the accepted answer gets *always* displayed before the other answer. However, I have noticed cases this does not happen, such as in this question:  [How to get Google Desktop to index searchable pdf's](https://superuser.com/questions/129454/how-to-get-google-desktop-to-index-searchable-pdfs).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When sorting by votes, the accepted answer is promoted to the top, regardless of votes - **unless** it's a self-answer, in which case normal vote sort is used without promotion.

See also:

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/

> **No change in sort order.** Normally, accepted answers are “docked” under the question. This is not true for owner accepted answers; they stay in standard sort order like any other answer.

[Accepted Answer not on top](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212197/187228)

> Accepted self-answers aren't pinned to the top.

[Self answer accepts should dock at the top, like any other post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93212/187228)